# Django Admin linking to related objects

Tags: django, django-admin

My app has users who create pages. In the `Page` screen of the admin, I'd like to list the `User` who created the page, and in that list, I'd like the username to have a link that goes to the user page in admin (not the `Page`).

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'user', )
    list_display_links = ('name','user',)
admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

I was hoping that by making it a link in the `list_display` it would default to link to the actual user object, but it still goes to `Page`.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add this to your model:

```
  def user_link(self):
      return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (reverse("admin:auth_user_change", args=(self.user.id,)) , escape(self.user))

  user_link.allow_tags = True
  user_link.short_description = "User"
```

You might also need to add the following to the top of `models.py`:

```
  from django.template.defaultfilters import escape
  from django.core.urls import reverse
```

In `admin.py`, in `list_display`, add `user_link`:

```
list_display = ('name', 'user_link', )
```

No need for `list_display_links`.

Comment: Thanks! to clarify, add that into my Page model?

Comment: Is it possible to do this on the actual change page rather than the listview?

Comment: That's the other model "auth_user" + underscore + "change" - so if the other model was frobnicate - it would be frobnicate_change.

Comment: Please... NO ONE do this. WhyNotHugo's answer is much cleaner.

Comment: user_link.allow_tags = True is not working for me. I have to return format_html("<a.....")

Answer (score 93):

Modifying your model isn't necessary, and it's actually a bad practice (adding admin-specific view-logic into your models? Yuck!) It may not even be possible in some scenarios.

Luckily, it can all be achieved from the ModelAdmin class:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe    


class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Add it to the list view:
    list_display = ('name', 'user_link', )
    # Add it to the details view:
    readonly_fields = ('user_link',)

    def user_link(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(
            reverse("admin:auth_user_change", args=(obj.user.pk,)),
            obj.user.email
        ))
    user_link.short_description = 'user'


admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

---

**Edit 2016-01-17:** 
Updated answer to use `make_safe`, since `allow_tags` is now deprecated.

**Edit 2019-06-14:**
Updated answer to use `django.urls`, since as of Django 1.10 `django.core.urls` has been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you, much better answer than the other one! (probably understandable, as Django has evolved a LOT since 2011...)

Comment: `readonly_fields = ('user_link')` not `read_only_fields = ('user_link')`

Comment: Better `obj.user.pk`, in case the primary key isn't called `id`.

Comment: May want to use `format_html('<a...{}..., mark_safe(reverse(...)), obj.user.email)` to escape the body of `<a>`, in case you don't trust it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html

Comment: can this be generalized to allow any related model in list_display to be hyperlinked?

Comment: for "auth_user_change" substitute "APP_MODEL_change" to generalize.

Answer (score 18):

You need to use [format_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) for modern versions of django

```
@admin.register(models.Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('ts', 'bar_link',)

    def bar_link(self, item):
        from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
        from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_urls import admin_urlname
        url = resolve_url(admin_urlname(models.Bar._meta, 'change'), item.bar.id)
        return format_html(
            '<a href="{url}">{name}</a>'.format(url=url, name=str(item.bar))
        )
```

Comment: Don't forget to also add " from django.utils.html import format_html "

Comment: By calling `'...'.format()` inside `format_html()`, you are actually bypassing the escaping mechanism... It should be: `format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, item.bar)` (replaced kwargs by args just for brevity)

Answer (score 14):

I ended up with a simple helper:

```py
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
from django.utils.safestring import SafeText
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_urls import admin_urlname
from django.utils.html import format_html


def model_admin_url(obj: Model, name: str = None) -> str:
    url = resolve_url(admin_urlname(obj._meta, SafeText("change")), obj.pk)
    return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, name or str(obj))
```

Then you can use the helper in your model-admin:

```py
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_field = ["my_link"]

    def my_link(self, obj):
        return model_admin_url(obj.my_foreign_key)
```

Comment: can you add how to use it?

Comment: @HarryMoreno sure, added

Comment: I suggest updating it to return "-" if obj is None so it can handle the case where the related object doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

I needed this for a lot of my admin pages, so I created a mixin for it that handles different use cases:

```sh
pip install django-admin-relation-links
```

Then:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django_admin_relation_links import AdminChangeLinksMixin


@admin.register(Group)
class MyModelAdmin(AdminChangeLinksMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

    # ...

    change_links = ['field_name']
```

See the GitHub page for more info. Try it out and let me know how it works out!

https://github.com/gitaarik/django-admin-relation-links

Comment: I tried it and it did not work for me, it may be because of the documentation.

Comment: @filtfilt can you please open an issue on the GitHub page describing your problem?

Comment: @filtfilt it was maybe because of the wrong ordering of the inheritance, you should put `AdminChangeLinksMixin` first. It was wrong in the readme, updated that now.

Comment: I added `change_links = ['model_name']`, but it still does not work :(. I get ´model_name: - ´ in the inlines, but nothing more. It may be because the model, which I have my `OneToOneField` to, is in a different application.

Comment: @filtfilt please open an issue on the GitHub page, no need to pollute this answer here on SO ;)

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Am adding it here so SO users can consider whether or not to try this. I had a look at your documentation. It is not clear on how to use. Please clarify how to use.

Comment: @Harlin Please open an issue on the GitHub project to get help. SO isn't the place to discuss these things.

Answer (score 5):

I decided to make a simple admin mixin that looks like this (see docstring for usage):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.utils.html import format_html
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse


class RelatedObjectLinkMixin(object):
    """    
    Generate links to related links. Add this mixin to a Django admin model. Add a 'link_fields' attribute to the admin
    containing a list of related model fields and then add the attribute name with a '_link' suffix to the
    list_display attribute. For Example a Student model with a 'teacher' attribute would have an Admin class like this:

    class StudentAdmin(RelatedObjectLinkMixin, ...):
        link_fields = ['teacher']

        list_display = [
            ...
            'teacher_link'
            ...
        ]
    """

    link_fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.link_fields:
            for field_name in self.link_fields:
                func_name = field_name + '_link'
                setattr(self, func_name, self._generate_link_func(field_name))

    def _generate_link_func(self, field_name):
        def _func(obj, *args, **kwargs):
            related_obj = getattr(obj, field_name)
            if related_obj:
                content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(related_obj.__class__)
                url_name = 'admin:%s_%s_change' % (content_type.app_label, content_type.model)
                url = reverse(url_name, args=[related_obj.pk])
                return format_html('<a href="{}" class="changelink">{}</a>', url, str(related_obj))
            else:
                return None
        return _func
```

Comment: You really don't need `ContentType` for this; you could just use `obj._meta.model` (or `obj.__class__`).

Comment: Stick `_func.short_description = field_name` before `return _func` otherwise all your columns will have the header "FUNC". This preserves the original name.

Comment: Here is an updated mixin that is working on Django 2.2 and includes the above recommendations https://gist.github.com/Vigrond/ac3c468377ce6d3e53f9b7059fd42569

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is trying to do this with inline admin, consider a property called [show_change_link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.show_change_link) since Django 1.8.

Your code could then look like this:

```
class QuestionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Question
    extra = 1
    show_change_link = True


class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (QuestionInline,)


admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

This will add a change/update link for each foreign key relationship in the admin's inline section.