# How to jump to a related model object via Django admin's list_display?

Tags: django

I do have a model `Comment` that relates to the model `Poller` via FK relationship.
Is there any way I can jump to this related object via the Django admin interface from the Comment's overview?

```
# Models.py

class Comment(models.Model):
    """
    A Class for comments made by users to a specific Poller
    """
    poller = models.ForeignKey(Poller, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='PollerComment')
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.ForeignKey(Vote, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
# Admin.py

@admin.register(Comment)
class PollerCommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'created_on', 'poller', 'comment', 'flag_count', 'upvote_count',
                    'downvote_count', 'is_public', 'is_removed')
```

Now I would like to make the 'poller' column clickable which will then redirect me to this poller object in the admin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Admin linking to related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418592/django-admin-linking-to-related-objects)

Comment: In addition to what @AvishkaDambawinna posted, this decorator implementation taken from Haki Benita's blog is useful if you plan to do this for multiple models: https://hakibenita.com/things-you-must-know-about-django-admin-as-your-app-gets-bigger#admin_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `poller` in `list_display` with a custom method that returns the desired link.

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
# [...]

@admin.register(Comment)
class PollerCommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'user', 'created_on', 'get_poller_link', 'comment', 'flag_count',
        'upvote_count','downvote_count', 'is_public', 'is_removed'
    )

    def get_poller_link(self, obj):
        # assuming poller is in the same app...
        return mark_safe('<a href="../poller/%s">%s</a>' % (obj.poller_id, obj.poller)

    get_poller_link.short_description = "Header to display"
    get_poller_link.admin_order_field = 'poller_id' # or another
```